# Извлечение части текста из всех строк колонки по условию

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas

Есть подобный датафрейм с множеством строк:

```
import pandas as pd
import re 

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':["{'fbclid': 'IwAR295tUiGCljtUzVYpJ6BMKwmbhOsfWOZzqVdpE29BbIfD4KigCupWriGuo_aem_AZscUccOW47NMeS9RpcIrjMVd2SrITSWAKZyukg-o4f6YwRd8KoxYrFuzlZGElx3rVgGdpf4C_i_JcW8Eeha7VzI', 'initial_utm_medium': 'EMPTY', 'initial_referring_domain': 'm.facebook.com'}",
                                   "{'initial_utm_medium': 'REFERRAL', 'initial_referring_domain': 'EMPTY', 'initial_utm_content': 'EMPTY', 'initial_utm_campaign': 'EMPTY', 'initial_twclid': 'EMPTY', 'initial_gclid': 'EMPTY', 'initial_utm_source': 'EMPTY', 'initial_dclid': 'EMPTY', 'initial_wbraid': 'EMPTY', 'initial_fbclid': 'EMPTY'}",
                                   '{}']})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно из колонки b извлечь значение initial_utm_medium, то есть все, что в кавычках после **'initial_utm_medium':** ,

то есть, например, для второй строки получить "REFERRAL" (повторяющийся один раз).

**Пробовала так:**

```
pattern = r"'initial_utm_medium'.\s*'(.+)\', "
df.b.str.extract(pattern)
```

Но на выходе получаю не совсем то, что нужно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу понять, как стопнуть захват текста после первой запятой после условия, помогите разобраться, пожалуйста :)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7060/178576)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Один из вариантов - не использовать регулярки, а преобразовать текст в словарь и забрать значение по ключу

```
df['extr'] = df.b.transform(eval).str['initial_utm_medium']
```

Для безопасного преобразования вместо `eval` можно использовать [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

С регуляркой:

```
df['extr'] = df.b.str.extract(r"'initial_utm_medium':\s'([^']*)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Вообще похоже на `JSON`, только кавычки неправильные. Если заменить кавычки, то парсится как `JSON`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3],'b':["{'fbclid': 'IwAR295tUiGCljtUzVYpJ6BMKwmbhOsfWOZzqVdpE29BbIfD4KigCupWriGuo_aem_AZscUccOW47NMeS9RpcIrjMVd2SrITSWAKZyukg-o4f6YwRd8KoxYrFuzlZGElx3rVgGdpf4C_i_JcW8Eeha7VzI', 'initial_utm_medium': 'EMPTY', 'initial_referring_domain': 'm.facebook.com'}",
                                   "{'initial_utm_medium': 'REFERRAL', 'initial_referring_domain': 'EMPTY', 'initial_utm_content': 'EMPTY', 'initial_utm_campaign': 'EMPTY', 'initial_twclid': 'EMPTY', 'initial_gclid': 'EMPTY', 'initial_utm_source': 'EMPTY', 'initial_dclid': 'EMPTY', 'initial_wbraid': 'EMPTY', 'initial_fbclid': 'EMPTY'}",
                                   '{}']})

df['initial_utm_medium'] = df.b.apply(lambda x: json.loads(x.replace("'", '"')).get('initial_utm_medium'))
df
```

Вывод:

```
    a   b                                              initial_utm_medium
0   1   {'fbclid': 'IwAR295tUiGCljtUzVYpJ6BMKwmbhOsfWO...   EMPTY
1   2   {'initial_utm_medium': 'REFERRAL', 'initial_re...   REFERRAL
2   3   {}                                                  None
```